# Primary hard drive too small

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd

The computer that I am working on has 10 gigs of free space. When running Photoshop and In-design, I keep running into issues where the computer doesn't have enough free space due to the files being so big.

I was thinking about adding a ssd to the computer and finding a way to partition the primary to r/w from the ssd as if they were both one hard drive. I was wondering if this was possible, or if it is even a good idea?

If it is, what is it called so I can look up how to do it. Or a link to a guide would be nice.

Thank you.

Comment: What you're looking for, I think, is a either a RAID0 set up, or disk stripping.  See here for details: http://lifehacker.com/5986883/how-to-combine-multiple-hard-drives-into-one-volume-for-cheap-high+capacity-storage

Comment: Your best best in this situation would be to buy a SSD (240 GB is recommended) and then image your current drive to the SSD and just use the SSD as your primary drive.   The solution that you have suggested would be difficult to do and would not leverage the speed advantage of the SSD as much as it would if you imaged your current setup to an SSD. 

How much data does your current hard drive have on it?  20GB?  40GB?  100GB?  500GB?

Comment: Obviously you want to purchase a SSD so it has sufficent space to hold all of your current data plus at least 100GB of free space so you do not run into this same situation again.
The tool I use to do this sort of thing is called Miray HDClone.   There is a freeware version available, but I think the author of the software limits the data transfer while cloning hard drives to 20/MBs.   If you want faster clone speeds, you will need to pay for one of the non free versions.

Comment: @Richie086 Ideally, he would only keep regularly used files and programs on the SSD.  This way, he gets the most benefit out of the drive, and then use a second drive as the primary long-term file store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is Intel Smart Response SSD Caching.  However, it wont solve your primary issue of not having enough disk space.  The cache will only speed access to that disk space.

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/raid/raid-ssd-cache.html

http://www.pcworld.com/article/248828/how_to_setup_intel_smart_response_ssd_caching_technology.html

The technology did not catch on because it doesn't work really well.  Performance gains were modest and did not justify the additional costs.  It was designed when SSD drives were not big enough to hold the entire OS.  That time has past and now you can get a SSD that will store your OS for around $100.

Their are two solutions to your problem.

First, and recommended, buy a new hard drive with sufficient space.  Mirror your existing drive to the new drive and expand the partition using GParted or any other capable tool such as Partition Magic.  You will now have sufficient space.  If you want to get that SSD boost you were looking for buy a hybrid drive that will have some onboard SSD cache.

Second, buy the SSD, but rather than using it as you are thinking, just add it to your system.  Once installed, you can move your Photoshop Scratch Disk to the new SSD.  You may also consider moving your system PageFile to that disk as well.

http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/photoshop/f/scratchdisk.htm

One final note, and the reason First is First.  Running a hard disk near capacity is a recipe for disaster.  When a hard disk is near capacity it is forced to write large files into the nooks and crannies between other files already stored.  This results in what is known as fragmentation.  Fragmentation happens all the time but when a disk is near capacity it is worst case scenario.  This fragmentation can become very severe and destroy performance.  Imagine if you had a notebook of papers and you stored each sheet in a different room, shoved under a couch or bed.  At the bottom of each sheet was written the location of the next sheet.  This is fragmentation.

Making matters worse, with little reserve space on the drive it becomes impossible to defragment the drive.  First things first, get some more space, then think about adding SSD.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate.  Sari could use the SSD as a secondary drive (which is not ideal, granted, but it is a solution) which would fill your requirement of getting more space.

Comment: Umm, that was option two.  Seems accurate to me, though option two as documented leaves a remaining problem of fragmentation of the primary disk.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about the "One final note" paragraph.  My comment was your option 2.  That being said, he could curb some of the concerns regarding fragmentation with the SSD, because that would allow him to off-load data, which would allow the main drive to be defragmented.  Note: Don't defragement SSD's.  They don't require it, and it reduces the life of the drive.